# Black shading appears while rendering

Tags: modeling

[image]While rendering this pipe model I get this dark shading. Why is this happening? Is there a particular reason for it?

[image]

how can i get rid of it??

Comment: Yes, there is a particular reason for it. My guess would be unexpected normals caused by overlapping edges. Could you add a screenshot with the modifier stack and the edit mode of the mesh?

Comment: I've added the screenshot of mesh in edit mode.How can i get rid that overlapping edges?